# What is the difference between scrollTop() method and scrollTop property in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am a bit confused to try to understand the difference between the jQuery method scrollTop() and property scrollTop. Actually i read about jQuery method scrollTop() at several places on Internet but very surprisingly i didn't read anywhere that scrollTop is also a jQuery property. I am not sure about it but though i saw in many code of animate() method, people using scrollTop: value to scroll the page. So please let me understand about this. Is there any resource on Internet which can tell scrollTop can also be used a property.

Comment: Nothing. `scrollTop()` is a wrapper for the native property. It's purpose is to save you having to access the underlying DOM object to get the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) method wraps the native [`Element.scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop) property.

That is, the `.scrollTop()` method belongs to [jQuery objects](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) while the property belongs to [native elements](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Element). The two won't be present in the same object.

---

> i saw in many code of animate() method, people using scrollTop: value to scroll the page

Yes, `scrollTop` is an animatable property. See [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) docs:

> In addition to style properties, some non-style properties such as `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft`, as well as custom properties, can be animated.

---

> Is there any resource on Internet which can tell scrollTop can also be used a property.

The [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) are the places to look for this information.

Comment: Yes right. I read the documentation and you also replied very nicely according to my various questions. Thanks.