# How do I run a jQuery function that is attached to a specific element on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

### My Issue

First of all, I am very new to jQuery, so I'm sure this is super simple but I really don't know how to do it. I currently have a jQuery function I wrote that returns the scroll position of a specific element and applies that value as a percent height for a progress bar elsewhere on the page. *See below:*

```js
$(".contentOuter").scroll(function() {
   var h = $(".content").height(); //the total height of the element to be scrolled
   var vh = window.innerHeight - 96; //the height of the viewbox I am scrolling in
   var sp = (this.scrollTop / (h - vh)) * 100; //the scroll position (my problem piece)
   var spb = $(".progressLineFill"); //the progress bar element
   spb.height(sp + "%"); //setting the height of the progress bar
});
```

I want to run this same function as soon as the page is loaded (just in case the element is already scrolled a little) but because I have included `this.scrollTop` I don't know how to translate that. I have tried setting a variable to replace the `this` in `this.scrollTop` but it seems to completely break everything. *See below:*

```js
var $elem = $(".contentOuter"); //new variable to replace the need for "this"

$(".contentOuter").scroll(function() {
   var h = $(".content").height();
   var vh = window.innerHeight - 96;
   var sp = ($elem.scrollTop / (h - vh)) * 100; //the new variable applied
   console.log(sp);
   var spb = $(".progressLineFill");
   spb.height(sp + "%");
});
```

I tried logging the value of `sp` (my scroll position variable) and I just get "NaN" in this configuration. Again, I am really inexperienced with jQuery.

### My Goal

I would like to isolate this function and be able to call it, both on scroll and on load.

### Conclusion

Again, I know this is probably super simple and I would love any suggestions!

*If I was unclear about anything, please let me know and I will update the question.*

Comment: You could use: $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});

Comment: `$elem.scrollTop` is a _method_, so you need to call it. `$elem` is a jQuery element, whereas `this` (inside the `.scroll` callback) is a native DOM element (which has a plain `.scrollTop` property which isn’t a method).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between scrollTop() method and scrollTop property in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445584/what-is-the-difference-between-scrolltop-method-and-scrolltop-property-in-jque). By the way, this confusion is one of the reasons I wouldn’t recommend using jQuery if you’re a beginner.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Perfect! I changed it to ```$elem.scrollTop()``` and it's working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: `$(".contentOuter").scroll(function{}).trigger("scroll");`

Comment: @CalvinBonner It was [not THAT simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66371376/295783)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```js
const myScroll = function() {
   var h = $(".content").height(); //the total height of the element to be scrolled
   var vh = window.innerHeight - 96; //the height of the viewbox I am scrolling in
   var sp = ($(this).scrollTop() / (h - vh)) * 100; //the scroll position (my problem piece)
   var spb = $(".progressLineFill"); //the progress bar element
   spb.height(sp + "%"); //setting the height of the progress bar
};
$(function() {
   $(".contentOuter")
    .scroll(myScroll)
    .trigger("scroll");
});
```

OR saving the element

```js
let $outer;
const myScroll = function() {
   var h = $(".content").height(); //the total height of the element to be scrolled
   var vh = window.innerHeight - 96; //the height of the viewbox I am scrolling in
   var sp = ($outer.scrollTop() / (h - vh)) * 100; //the scroll position (my problem piece)
   var spb = $(".progressLineFill"); //the progress bar element
   spb.height(sp + "%"); //setting the height of the progress bar
};
$(function() {
   $outer = $(".contentOuter");
   $outer.on("scroll",myScroll)
   myScroll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe such sulution will work

```
 let $elem = $('.contentOuter'), yourFunction;

 yourFunction = () => {
      //your code
 }

 $(window).load(yourFunction())
 $elem.sroll(yourFunction())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this doesn't solve my original issue though being that I couldn't get the ```scrollTop``` to work without putting ```this``` before it because I was using it as a DOM element and not a method.